# I have an Android app which is converted to iOS app using Xamarin. I want to use a single appium script to automate both

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

Is it possible? Both the apps have different element details. Can this be fixed from dev team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by using the Page Object model and `PageFactory` utility class. While describing your screens as page objects, you can specify different locators per platform. For example:

```java
public class LoginView extends BaseView {

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "email")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "email")
    private MobileElement emailInput;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "password")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "password")
    private MobileElement passwordInput;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "submit")
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "submit")
    private MobileElement submitButton;

    public LoginView(AppiumDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public void login(String username, String password) {
        emailInput.click();
        emailInput.type(username);
        passwordInput.click();
        passwordInput.type(password);
        submitButton.click();
    }
}
```

In BaseView you need to pass driver instance and initialize elements, e.g. this way:

```java
abstract class BaseView {
    protected AppiumDriver driver;

    public BaseView(AppiumDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Now, you only need to grab locators for your elements on different platforms, all the rest will be handled by PageFactory.

Hope this helps